# Redis Exited While Run With Persistent Data In Boot2Docker

Tags: macos, redis, docker, boot2docker

I use boot2docker to run docker containers in OSX. I have pull redis, and want to run it with persistent data. But it always exited when I run the container.
Here command I used

`docker run --name dynomapper-redis -d redis redis-server -v /Users/dolly/redis-data:/data --appendonly yes`

If I remove `-v` options redis will run and not exited. I just curious if there are permission problem.

Here the error message when run it with `-v` option

`Redis server v=3.0.3 sha=00000000:0 malloc=jemalloc-3.6.0 bits=64 build=bf300626cfd5c55b`